# How do I know if I can use LHDC in my Android phone?

Tags: settings, bluetooth, bluetooth-audio, hardware-requirements

I have a Xiaomi 11 Lite 5G NE and I would like to know

1. Whether it can support the LHDC function provided by Xiaomi Buds 3T Pro.
2. If the above is a yes, how do I know I am using that codec? [Will the word "LHDC" be displayed alongside with the Bluetooth device?]

I have searched many websites but cannot get a definite answer.

In my phone, I discovered the following: Settings > ... > Developer ... > Bluetooth ... and besides "SBC", "AptX" and ...., "LHDC" is an allowable choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In my phone, I discovered the following:- setting > ... > developer ... > Bluetooth ... and besides "SBC" , AptX" and ...., "LHDC" is an allowable choice.

**If "LHDC" is mentioned in the settings then your phone supports LHDC.** So...

1. Yes, it supports LHDC (most Xiaomi and others support it since at least 2021).
2. Yes, the acronym "LHDC" will appear at the right of the Bluetooth audio device's name. That said it may not be selected by default. If that's the case then you need to tap the arrow (>), scroll down and enable the codec.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, after pairing Xiaomi Buds 3T Pro with Xiaomi 11 Lite 5G NE, the codec can only go up to AAC but not LHDC. Sad. This is because the HD audio has been factory pre-set as deactivated. Methods of re-activating it are welcome.